# QR Code Scanner App works perfectly EXCEPT in Nougat

Tags: android, qr-code, android-7.0-nougat

Been a while since I last asked a question here. Googled, Stack-Overflowed, etc - feels like no one else had this problem.

Anyway, I created an app for a client that reads a QR Code from their employees' ID to time them in or out; a bundy clock with a twist. I am not very good with Android programming but I am good with programming in general; my background is in Visual Basic and Java. I used Google's Vision API for the camera and it works beautifully. I used API-17 since the only available tablet I have for testing runs on Jelly Bean.

So, my client buys a tablet for the app and it runs on Nougat 7.0. For some reason, the SurfaceView just sits there. It can "see" but it does not read the QR Code. I tap it to auto-focus, even change the preferred camera (that I built into my code), and it still does not read any QR code. I installed my app in devices running Kitkat, Lollipop, Marshmallow, Oreo, even Pie and they all work EXCEPT the one running Nougat! I haven't tried installing it in another device with Nougat though and I might do that after this posting - maybe it's the device itself? It's a Huawei Mediapad M3 Lite and runs on its own custom OS based on Nougat so it could also be that.

But, just in case I missed something, maybe someone with a lot more expertise on Android programming here can help shed some light on this mystery.

UPDATE: I installed my app in a Nougat-7.1 device and it worked. I reinstalled the app in the Mediapad M3 Lite, still NOT working. I am inclined to believe that this issue might have something to do with Nougat-7.0 or the Custom OS of Huawei (EMUI 5.1.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. It had something to do with the Custom OS - EMUI. I played around with the tablet and found an "additional permissions" setting somewhere in the Advanced section of Settings. I allowed it to run "debug" apps and it worked. Weird thing is, the app did run but just did not read the QR Code. But this option seem to have fixed it and revealed a new one.

I included a REGEX validation of the codes it should read and throws an error if the QR code is invalid. Now, it just reads ANY QR Code and skips validation. I checked all other devices I installed the app in and all Androids from Lollipop and up had the same issue - they all skipped validation. However, Kitkat and Jelly Bean did the validation perfectly. This one I should be able to figure out on my own with some research.

For those who read my post and got confused as well, I apologize.